# Missing "Deploy"-Button Visual Studio 2012

Tags: 2010, 2013, solution-deployment, visual-studio-2012

Yesterday I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Premium on my SharePoint 2013 Development Machine. I also installed the Office Developer Tools to get the SP2013 Project templates.

Opening my SP 2010 Solution File and converting to 2013 was successful.

**My problem:** 
There is no "Deploy"-Button in the Project-Context-Menu anymore. Everything is there: Build, Rebuild, Retract etc.

But no Deploy.

Comment: It is hard to say that this is SharePoint specific. IF the button was there before installations of SharePoint the question can be reopened

Comment: I think it is SharePoint specific because I have to install the Office Developer Tools only for SharePoint 2013. After installing this package the button is missing. I will ask that on SO. Hopefully anybody had the same problem and fixed it.

Comment: [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997020/missing-deploy-button-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: I think this is SharePoint related enough - you get an answer here more likely than on SO because the SO guys rarely install SP extensions ;)

Comment: That was also my thought ;)

Comment: I have reopened it, seems it is related to Office Dev tools :)

Comment: Is the Deploy menu item present at the solution level in the tree?

Comment: Yes it is visible in the solution context menu. But i do not want to deploy the whole solution :( only a Project in the solution.